# how to Hide and show the open $uibModal.open

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

$uibModalInstance.close() is closed the modal but
couldn't find any option to hide and show it.
Is there any option to hide and show the open modal or we have to use css to hide and show it.
Thanks

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Are you using Angular? $uibModal is the Angular implementation of a bootstrap modal.